# show multiple images on multiple click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i display multiple images inside a div ? I have a library of images & i want to show the images inside a div when i click on them.

Lets say i want the dog image 3 times so i click on the dog 3 times & i want the cat image 2 times so i click 2 times. What would the java script be for doing this on click ?

One more thing how can i make the image disappear when the second drop down shows the image ?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

function clickedPhoto(src) {
  modalImg.src = src;
}



function fctCheck(imajes) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(imajes).style.display = "block";
}
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  $("#dogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'smalldog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
$('#cat').on('change', function() {
  $("#catimges").css('display', (this.value == 'smallcat') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>


<select id="images" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
  <option value="">Choose Image</option>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>


<select id="dog" name="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="smalldog">small dog</option>

</select>

<select id="cat" name="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="smallcat">small cat</option>

</select>


<div style='display:none;' id="dogimges">
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55" onclick="clickedPhoto(this.src)">
  </div>
</div>


<div style='display:none;' id="catimges">
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55" onclick="clickedPhoto(this.src)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u explain me about your last question "One more thing how can i make the image disappear when the second drop down shows the image ?" i dont understand

Comment: The img in the drop down doesn't disappear when you select another image. If you select the dog first and then the cat the dog doesn't disappear its hard to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery then use the functionality of it. Did few modifications see if this what you were looking for. This code can be further optimized.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#images').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
  $('.subselector').on('change', function() {
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();

    $("#" + id + "imges").css('display', 'block');
  });

  $('img').on('click', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#myModal').append('<img class="modal-content" src="' + src + '">');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>


<select id="images">
  <option value="">Choose Image</option>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>


<select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="smalldog">small dog</option>
</select>

<select id="cat" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="smallcat">small cat</option>
</select>


<div style='display:none;' id="dogimges" class="smallimages">
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
</div>


<div style='display:none;' id="catimges" class="smallimages">
  <div data-image="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if i want to have small dog, medium dog, and large dog all under dog cattegory what do i do i tried and i get the same picture

Comment: i would like to have more images under each dog like small dog to have more dogs and medium with multiple dogs to choose from

Comment: Then build markup like that and modify the js code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickedPhoto=(function(){
   var id=0;
   function fun(src) {

   var str=" <img class='modal-content' id='img"+id+"' src="+src+">";
   modal.innerHTML= modal.innerHTML+str;
   id+=1;
   }
   return fun;
})();
```

remove content inside div id myModal